# Hamming distance in k-means clustering

Tags: matlab, hamming-distance

I want to use the hamming distance in kmeans clustering in Matlab, but I get an error saying that my data must be binary.

Is there anyway around this? The data matrix that I use can't be binary (it has a physical interpretation that must allow for values 0,1,2,3) but it's important that I use the Hamming distance.

Answer (score 1):

Per the MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/kmeans.html), the Hamming distance measure for `kmeans` can only be used with binary data, as it's a measure of the percentage of bits that differ.

You could try mapping your data into a binary representation before using the function. You could also look at using the city block distance as an alternative if possible, as it is suitable for non-binary input.

Comment: Thanks, I mapped the distance matrix into a binary representation using de2bi in matlab. This enables me to use the hamming distance with kmeans but now the distance matrix has a different size, resulting in more elements in my clustering. I can't use the taxicab distance, not suitable for my interpretation of my original matrix...

Answer (score 1):

The data to cluster must be of type logical. You can convert your 0/1 double, single, uintX data by a single command:

```
x = logical( y );
```

If you want to convert uint8 type data to binary, check the function *uint8tobit*(). Take a look at *de2bi*() and *bi2de*() functions.